# Facebook Open Graph, submit review of story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am beginning at facebook development and trying to create a story using open graph. 
My story is '[User] [Recommands] a [Partner]' and I already created both object (Partner) and action (Recommand).
The point is when I ask FB to review my action I am answered the following message :

> Thanks for making changes to your submission. This action type still doesn’t meet our criteria to become available to users. Here are the remaining changes that you need to make to your action type:
>
> It needs to be clear to the user that you’ll be publishing a story to Facebook and that you’ll get their permission before actually publishing the story. Actions must not be confusing or misleading and should accurately represent the action the user took within your app. A "partager" (share) button should not trigger a "recommend" action, please change your UEX so it is clear to the user which action will take place.
>
> Once you’ve made the changes, I’ll review your submission within 3 business days.

I do not really understand what is meant by "It needs to be clear to the user that you’ll be publishing a story to Facebook". Does it mean that I need to post an Open Graph story using a Dialog box ? I thought we can't do that anymore ...
If you have good examples of personalized stories using Open Graph please share it with me, in order to understand what is expected by FBook.

Does anyone know what "change your UEX" means ? I did a quick Google research but did not find a meaningful answer ...

Thank you !
Flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UEX mean User Experience, also sometimes called UX.  It's how users interact with your application.

What they mean is that they don't want the user to click on a button that says "Share", but then post something to their FB Timeline that says they "Recommend" something.   So, the user thinks they are just sharing, but all of sudden they are also recommending it. Facebook wants your button (or some text or another indicator) that says something "Recommend This!".  This lets the user know that they are recommending something to their friends.

Or, conversely, you could change your Open Graph action to be "Share" instead.